# AngularJS dynamically populate details from json based on item selected

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to create a page where you have few items in a list group which when selected should show more details.

Please view the example here http://plnkr.co/edit/Oava3pA9OTsm80K58GdT?p=preview

How can I populate the details from the json file based on the item that is selected in the list group?

This is what I have so far.

**html:**

```
<div ng-controller=ItemsController>
    <h3>Test</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <ul class="list-group">
            <a class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in itemDetails">{{item.name}}</a>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <h2>Name: </h2>
          <br />Address Line 1:
          <br />Address Line 2:
          <br />Suburb:
          <br />Phone:
          <br />Email:
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**script:**

```
var myItemsApp = angular.module('myItemsApp', []);

myItemsApp.factory('itemsFactory', ['$http', function($http){
  var itemsFactory ={
    itemDetails: function() {
      return $http(
      {
        url: "mockItems.json",
        method: "GET",
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
        });
      }
    };
    return itemsFactory;

}]);


myItemsApp.controller('ItemsController', ['$scope', 'itemsFactory', function($scope, itemsFactory){
  var promise = itemsFactory.itemDetails();

    promise.then(function (data) {
        $scope.itemDetails = data;
        console.log(data);
    });
}]);
```

**json:**

```
[
   {
      "$id":"1",
      "name":"Test itemName 1",
      "themeName":"ASD",
      "addressLine1":"18 Banksia Street",
      "addressLine2":null,
      "suburb":"Heidelberg",
      "state":"VIC",
      "postalCode":"3084",
      "contactPhone":"+61 3 123456",
      "emailAddress":"qwerty.it@xyz.com"
   },
   {
      "$id":"2",
      "name":"Test itemName 2",
      "themeName":"WER",
      "addressLine1":"11 Riverview Place",
      "addressLine2":"Metroplex on Gateway",
      "suburb":"Murarrie",
      "state":"QLD",
      "postalCode":"4172",
      "contactPhone":"1300 73123456",
      "emailAddress":"asdfg.it@xyz.com"
   },
   {
      "$id":"3",
      "name":"Test itemName 3",
      "themeName":"ERT",
      "addressLine1":"60 Waterloo Road",
      "addressLine2":null,
      "suburb":"North Ryde",
      "state":"NSW",
      "postalCode":"2113",
      "contactPhone":"123456",
      "emailAddress":"zxcvb.it@xyz.com"
   }
]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am very new to programming. Please also feel free to alternative ways of achieving this if I have done it wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the ng-click directive to specify what happens when you click something.

So I made it assign the clicked item to the `$scope.selected` object using a function (`$scope.select(item)`) and then I bound the properties of that object to your little details section. That's probably the simplest way to do it.

Ctrl

```
$scope.select = function(item) {
  $scope.selected = item;
}
$scope.selected = {};
```

HTML

```
<a class="list-group-item" ng-click="select(item)" ng-repeat="item in itemDetails">
  {{item.name}}
</a>
```

And the `selected` object is then available like this:

```
<h2>Name: {{selected.name}}</h2>
etc...
```

See my example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/mUMZ0VGO8l1ufV1JJNQE?p=preview

Comment: And yes, your code looks really nice for someone who's new to programming. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works like a charm. I wish I could give you a rep score. Unfortunately I do not have enough to actually vote yet. About the code, its mainly from examples on stack overflow. I still have a lot to learn. I really enjoy angularJS :)

Comment: You're welcome. No worries, with more questions like that, you'll get a lot of rep in no time! :)

Comment: How do you update that to default to the first item from the JSON file?

Comment: @mrtonyb Not sure what exactly you mean, but you should be able to set the default value by setting `$scope.selected` to the first JSON item as soon as the JSON is ready.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I meant. When loading the page, have the ID:1 data displayed in the HTML. I added this: $scope.selected = data[0];
It worked for me.

Comment: this has made my work so much easier! Thank you!! One question or addition - is it possible to highlight the selected row? I'm using divs and I want to highlight the div I select

Comment: @user1397978 You're welcome! Yes, sure, you can use `ng-class` to dynamically assign a class to your div based on a condition.